# How to get decimal degrees instead meters from X Y coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I created a new project with decimal degrees system. Then I created a new layer and created a point on it. When I click on my point I see in attributes X and Y attributes in decimal degrees but when I try to create a new field with function `concat($y,' ', $x )` it displays value in meters instead degrees. What I have to do for get value in decimal degrees?
QGIS 3.12

Comment: What coordinate system did you pick when creating the layer

Comment: It was EPSG:3395. But after your question and MrXsquared's answer I try to change it to EPSG:4326 and my function worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
concat(y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')),' ',x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')))
```

It transforms coordinates from every known crs to wgs 84.

Comment: Thank you! It works.